# How can I play an audio that can be dismissed by screen lock button on iPhone

Tags: ios, audio

I am working on a VOIP application on iPhone and I have some trouble doing the incoming ringtone feature. I want the incoming ringtone can be played in both background and phone locked state. And the ringer can be dismissed by iPhone's hardware buttons similar to native phone call behavior.
1. Ringer should be muted when user pressed screen lock
2. When mute button is on, ringer should be muted.

I cannot work it out by seeting audio session category to playback mode or ambient. Playback category cannot support screen lock and mute button. Ambient category cannot support background audio. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

In order to silence audio from volume button changes on the phone you need to register for the notification below:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(volumeChangedDuringDisconnectionAlert:) name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

Then in your selector function, either silence your alert or do whatever you would like with it.

And as for silencing audio when the user unlocks the screen, you'll most likely have to pick it up in either the `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` or `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` functions inside of the app delegate.

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: For volumn button control, I have a way to deal with it. But I think the screen lock control is not as simple as you suggested. Because I want to silence the audio when screen lock is pressed not the opposite.